# Combining Streams In Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I am trying to combine streams into a single stream that returns a boolean which shows if both streams have values. i am using the new stream to activate a button if both values are not empty.
Here is my bloc

// import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

```
class VotingBloc {
   final numVotes = PublishSubject<String>();
   final pin = PublishSubject<String>();

  Function(String) get votesChanged => numVotes.sink.add;
  Function(String) get pinChanged => pin.sink.add;

Stream<bool> get submitCheck => CombineLatestStream.combine2(numVotes, pin, (a, b) => true);


 dispose() {
  numVotes.close();
  pin.close();
}
}

final votingBloc = VotingBloc();
```

In my main screen, printing snapshot.data gives me null.

```
Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
      child: StreamBuilder<Object>(
        stream: votingBloc.submitCheck,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          print(snapshot.data);
          return RaisedButton(
            // elevation: 5.0,
            onPressed: snapshot.hasData ? () => print('object') : null ,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            color: Color(0xfff64c72),
            child: Text(
              'VOTE NOW',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                letterSpacing: 1.5,
                fontSize: 18.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      ),
    ),
```

How best can i recreate this?

Comment: Have you tried using `Observable.CombineLatest2` or `Rx.combineLatest2` depending on your version of Dart and RxDart? I took a tutorial course before that had something similar to this and it used `Observable.CombineLatest2` I think since the 2.6 update on Dart it should use `Rx.CombineLatest2` though.

Comment: i also think that @kobowo suggestion could work for you. if it didn’t work then try to use behaviour subject and add a code of textfield to.